# Python/Pygame, Where do I put my pygame.time.wait loop?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I am in the middle of making two, very similar games (Exact details are irrelevant right now.)

Anyway, I need to know where to insert my "pygame.time.wait" code.

The exact code I need looks like this:

```
pygame.time.wait(100)
score = score + 1
```

Currently, my code looks like so:

```
import sys, pygame

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 800,500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("One Score (Created by - Not Really Working Lamp Productions:)")

WHITE = (255,255,255)
score = 0
screen.fill (WHITE)

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 16)

scoretext = myfont.render("Score = "+str(score), 1, (0,0,0))
screen.blit(scoretext, (5, 10))

disclaimertext = myfont.render("Copyright, 2013, Not Really Working Lamp Productions.", 1, (0,0,0))
screen.blit(disclaimertext, (5, 480))

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.display.flip()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:sys.exit()
```

The problem is though, that I don't know WHERE in this code I should put my pygame.time.wait code. Could anybody fill me in? (I think it goes in the "while 1:" loop, but I don't know where.)

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon. You should put your 'wait code' into the body of FOR circle:

```
while 1:         
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.display.flip()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:sys.exit()
        pygame.time.wait(100)
        score = score + 1
```

Comment: The program no longer runs after I add that in.

Comment: What was the error ? I run this program on PyCharm and it's working.

Comment: Wait, never mind, it is working, but the text won't change as the variable goes up. Terribly sorry for the mistake.